# Given an array of arrays, how can I strip out the substring "GB" from each value?

Tags: php, arrays, substring

Each item in my array is an array of about 5 values.. Some of them are numerical ending in "GB".. I need the same array but with "GB" stripped out so that just the number remains.

So I need to iterate through my whole array, on each subarray take each value and strip the string "GB" from it and create a new array from the output.

Can anyone recommend and efficient method of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`array_walk_recursive()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) for this:

```
array_walk_recursive($arr, 'strip_text', 'GB');

function strip_text(&$value, $key, $string) {
  $value = str_replace($string, '', $value);
}
```

It's a lot less awkward than traversing an array with its values by reference (correctly).

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own custom function to iterate through an array's value's, check if the substring `GB` exists, and if so, remove it. With that function you can pass the original array and the function into [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr = ...

foreach( $arr as $k => $inner ) {
   foreach( $inner as $kk => &$vv ) {
      $vv = str_replace( 'GB', '', $vv );
   }
}
```

This actually keeps the original arrays intact with the new strings. (notice `&$vv`, which means that i'm getting the variable by reference, which means that any changes to `$vv` within the loop will affect the actual string, not by copying)

Answer (score 1):

```
// i only did the subarray part
$diskSizes = array("500", "300 GB", "200", "120 GB", "130GB");
$newArray = array();

foreach ($diskSizes as $diskSize) {
    $newArray[] = str_replace('GB', '', $diskSize);


}

// look at the new array
print_r($newArray);
```